# In Oracle 11G XE, how can we get comma separated list of column names in correct order to be used in control file of sqlldr to import csv file?

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle11g

I have to import csv files in oracle 11g xe. For mysql I directly used mysqlimport or load data infile which did not need column names. For oracle it looks like list of column names is mandatory. How can I generate the list of column names in correct order?

Comment: How are you generating the .csv file?

Comment: I am using an external tools for that (TPC-DS benchmark tool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the data dictionary to get the column names, e.g.:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE owner = 'TABLE_OWNER'
AND table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
ORDER BY column_id;
```

Comment: Blank result with message 'no rows selected'. If I try describe TABLE_NAME, it works fine and prints the column names and types.

Comment: That means you have either the wrong owner name or table name in the query.

Comment: Run `select owner, table_name from all_tables` to see what tables your session can see.

Comment: Silly me, the table names were in uppercase in all_tab_columns table. Works.